# TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime method not converting the DateTime correctly

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I have the following date string: `2015-11-10T23:52:18.5245011Z`
And when I parse it using DateTime.Parse method it returns  `11/11/2015 10:52:18 AM` which is incorrect.

I also tried the follwing conversion:

```
TimeZoneInfo est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime targetTimeUtcconverted = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(UtcDate, est);
```

and it still gives out: `11/11/2015 10:52:18 AM`

Can't figure out what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind)
```

Or:

```
DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal)
```

Or (best option):

```
DateTimeOffset.Parse(s)
```

By default, `DateTime.Parse` will adjust to local time if there is any offset information present in the string.  Since `Z` is the same as `+00:00`, it assumes the input is +00:00, then adjusts from UTC to the local time zone.

If there is no offset information present, it returns a `DateTime` with `Unspecified` kind.

Passing `DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind` tells it to treat any value with an offset as local time (as before), but any value containing `Z`, `UTC`, `GMT`, etc. to have `DateTimeKind.Utc`.

Passing `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` tells it that the output should *always* have `DateTimeKind.Utc`, and the value should be adjusted if necessary.

Parsing using `DateTimeOffset.Parse` bypasses all of that convoluted behavior and just returns a value with an offset matching what was provided.  This is the best approach when an offset (or `Z`) is present in the input string.  If you need a `DateTime`, you can use the `UtcDateTime`, `LocalDateTime`, or `DateTime` properties from the resulting `DateTimeOffset`.

The time zone conversion code you gave is correct, as long as the `Kind` is UTC.  It would be more explicit to use `ConvertTimeFromUtc`, but that wouldn't really matter in this case.  The best approach is to use the overload of `ConvertTime` that works with `DateTimeOffset` values.  The resulting value will be a `DateTimeOffset` whose `DateTime` property matches the time in that time zone, and whose `Offset` property is the correct offset for that time in that time zone.

Comment: Thanks mate!! I used the last strategy `DateTimeOffset.Parse(s)` and it worked like a charm.